# Trigger SQL command at a specific time since the current time

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
    Id                  INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Maker               INT NOT NULL,
    Target              INT NOT NULL,
    [From]              DateTime NOT NULL,
    [To]                DateTime NOT NULL,
    Note                NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    Created             FLOAT NOT NULL,
    LastModified        FLOAT,
    LastModifiedNote    NVARCHAR(128),
    [Status]            TINYINT NOT NULL

    FOREIGN KEY (Maker) REFERENCES Person(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Target) REFERENCES Person(Id)
)
```

Let me explain some information in my table: this table is about an appointment information between person and person. `[From]` is when the appointment should be started, `[To]` is the time when appointment should be ended.

All I want to do is :

- When the appointment is created, check the time `[To]`, at the time appointment should be ended, a query is run to change the `[Status]` to **4 (Expired)**
- When the appointment is edited, check the time `[To]` and do the same thing as the step above

For example:

- At **9.am**, I created an appointment with **[To]** is **2016/07/29 5:00 pm**, so at **5:00 pm**, a query should be run to change the **[Status]** of this appointment to **4**
- At **10 am**, I edited this appointment, I change **[To]** to **2016/07/29 7:00 pm**, instead the appointment is changed that status at **5.00 pm**, now it is changed its status at **7:00 pm**.

I think I should use trigger and event, but I don't know how to achieve my goal.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: How else is status used? If it's value can always be determined from other data, you might want to consider not storing it at all - or making it a computed column.

Comment: [Status] is to show whether the appointment is Active or Expired. 1 : Active , 4 is Expired.

Comment: you should create trigger on insert and update

Comment: Can you show me how ? Because I'm new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a trigger, but that will not solve your problem. What you want is something that will run in the background and will change the status of expired appointments to 4 when they expire.

There are different ways to achieve this. One very easy way is to create a SQL Server Job Agent job that will execute periodically, for example once every 5 minutes or even 1 minute.

In SQL Server Management Studio locate your server, at the end you should see the SQL Server Job Agent. Expand it and create a new job under Jobs. Inside put one step with code like this.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Status=4
FROM Appointment A
WHERE A.Status<>4 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP>A.[To]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm.. If the query runs 5 mins per minute, I think it can cause server overloaded.

Comment: @Redplane: With a proper index on Status and To date the update will be very quick. Scheduling it will make it update all rows that have changed in a period of time, so it will be less overloading the server then individual updates.

Comment: I've read about SQL Job, it doesn't meet my real time need but the speed is fast as you say, I think I should use the SQL Job. Thank you for your answer :)